# Anonymous Posting Option

Tags: feature-request, questions

Personal finance can be an area where sometimes a user would be discouraged from asking a question knowing that his or her StackExchange profile will be linked to the question for all the world to see.  For example, a user may not want those in his or her circle to that he or she may be considering bankruptcy or has enough liquid cash for certain types of accounts.  It'd be nice if there were an option (checkbox) to post a question anonymously.  The idea is that the user would still have to be logged in to post, and site admins/moderators may still be able to see who posted, but the user's ID would be withheld from public view.

Comment: You don't actually need an account to post on Stack Exchange - if you log out and try to ask a question, you'll find that you can. You need to supply an email address, but that's only visible to mods and SE employees.

Comment: @senshin That's great, but then it doesn't show up in the user's own Q&A history.

Comment: I like this idea and I think there are a number of other StackExchange sites where it would be useful - particularly `workplace`. Might be worth bringing it up on meta.stackexchange.com to get a wider audience?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam It looks like it's already been brought up.  Please take a look and support: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136422/ability-to-ask-questions-anonymously-but-still-get-notifications

Comment: I just tried logging out to post anonymously, but it won't let because it says that my email address is already registered.  This feature would be easy to implement; it sucks there is so little interest in developing it.